# DateFormat.is24HourFormat won't work inside class

Tags: android

Code:

```
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Created by Chris on 2/17/2018.
 */

public class Crime {

    private UUID mId;
    private String mTitle;
    private Date mDate;
    private boolean mSolved;
    private boolean mRequiresPolice;
    private Calendar mCalendar;



   public Crime(){
    mId = UUID.randomUUID();
    mDate = new Date();
    mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
}


....

public String getFormattedTime(){

    if (DateFormat.is24HourFormat());

    return DateFormat.format("HH:mm", mDate).toString();
}
```

Issue:

I can't get DateFormat.is24HourFormat to resolve in my getFormattedTime() method.  Using "this", "getContext", "getApplicationContext", does not work. It works fine in another class I have, which is just an extension of a DialogFragment.  I'm probably being dumb, but I can not figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DateFormat.is24HourFormat()** needs a **context** as a parameter because the method checks the user preferences.
"*this*" won't work in your class crime as this is not an Activity.

You can do this :

```
public String getFormattedTime(Context context){

    if (DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context));

    return DateFormat.format("HH:mm", mDate).toString();
}
```

And then  from your activity call

```
String time = mycrime.getFormattedTime(this)
```

Comment: Ah, okay.  That makes sense.  I figured it was something of the sort, I just couldn't pinpoint it.

Thanks!

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.